# Getting incorrect cell subview frame sizes in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom TablViewCell, that is a self-sizing cell (UITableViewAutomaticDimension). Therefore, I am not using heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Anyway, I have a view on there that is 1 pixel high, and takes up about 90% of the cell's width. Just a long thin line.

I CANNOT get the accurate width of this line. I keep getting the width of the line as per the storyboard, and not what it's actual size on the device is.

I could probably hack my way to getting it by caching the width of the controller view in viewWillAppear, and then subtracting the leading/trailing constraints to figure out the width, but that's ridiculous.

Does anyone know how I can get the accurate frame width, and general frame sizing, of a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath right after dequeueing?

code:

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PlayerQuestionDetailCell";
    FFFPlayerQuestionDetailTableViewCell *percentageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [percentageCell updateColors];

    ...


        NSLog(@"Line4: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(percentageCell.lineVertical4.frame));
        NSLog(@"Line3: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(percentageCell.lineVertical3.frame));
        NSLog(@"Top: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(percentageCell.lineTop.frame));
        NSLog(@"P1: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(percentageCell.percentageLine1.frame));

        NSLog(@"LastLine: %f, AllLines: %f", lengthOfLastPercentageLine, percentageLineLength);
        NSLog(@"TopWidth: %f", percentageCell.lineTop.frame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"BottomWidth: %f", percentageCell.lineBottom.frame.size.width);

        NSLog(@"CellWidth1: %f", percentageCell.frame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"CellWidth2: %f", percentageCell.contentView.frame.size.width);

        ...
```

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: @Bannings Ok posted!

Comment: You can't. The cell isn't added to the table view yet. Look into the `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy unfortunately this advice not work in my case, [please, check my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733266/get-updated-x-coord-of-frame-of-cell-item)